# Finding the integration by using residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi I am trying to find the following integral

$$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{z^{17}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}dz$$

There are 5 pole of different order and the calculation is very tedious.

I was wondering if there's any shorter way to find the integral by using residues.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, use the residue at $\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Oh I remember now. Thank you very much. By the way I got the answer as $2\pi i$, Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Without mentioning the residue at $\infty$, Cauchy's integral theorem says the integral doesn't depend on the radius of the circle, as long as it's larger than $\sqrt[3]{3}$. Thus letting the radius tend to $+\infty$ and noting that for large $\lvert z\rvert$ the integrand is $z^{-1} + O(z^{-2})$ leads to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Inasmuch as all of the residues of $f(z)=\frac{z^{17}}{(z^2+2)^3(z^3+3)^4}$ are on the open disk $|z|<3$, we can use the suggestion by @DanielFischer,  Proceesing, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=3}f(z)\,dz&=-2\pi i \text{Res}(f(z),z=\infty)\\\\
&=2\pi i\text{Res} \left( \frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right), z=0\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{(1+2z^2)^3(1+3z^3)^4}\\\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, we can deform the contour $|z|=3$ to the contour $|z|=R$ where $R$ is chosen large enough to enclose all poles.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=3}f(z)\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^{17}e^{i17\phi}}{R^{18}e^{i18\phi}\left(1+\frac{2}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)^3\left(1+\frac{3}{R^3e^{i3\phi}}\right)^4}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&=i2\pi
\end{align}$$

since $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{im\phi}\,d\phi=0$ for $m\ne 0$.

Note, that we could also have simply let $R\to \infty$ and arrived at the same result without exploiting the fact that $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{im\phi}\,d\phi=0$ for $m\ne 0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark